# How to connect to remote server in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: apache, ubuntu, aptana

I have following web server configuration

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

Web Server: Apache 2.2.22

PHP: PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.21

MySQL: 5.5.47

- Virtual Host for web project 'MyWebSiteName001' is created in Apache server using Webmin.
- 'user001' is created under User Accounts and has Administrative privileges.

I have successfully installed Aptana Studio 3 on my computer. I also created new web project named 'MyWebSiteName001'. Now when I go to Create New Connections' option and try to connect to remove server project in FTP mode using user001/password, it is giving below error.

**establishing ftp connection failed connection: refused connection**

So I am not sure what I am missing or wrong I am doing and thus I am not able to connect to remote server. So please let me know how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a ftp account first and then configure Aptana using this acconunt.
If you are using FileZilla Edit-->Users (here configure user, password, folders and permissions).
Hope this helps.